# django reversion - revert related field to the same version

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-reversion

I have two models:

```
class Plan(models.Model):
    ...

class Sales(models.Model):
    plan = models.ForeignKey(Plan)
```

I registered these models in django-reversion:

```
reversion.register(Plan, follow=['sales_set'])
reversion.register(Sales)
```

So, when I get an old version of Plan with old information in it, I tried to get related objects for this old version of Plan like this:

```
version.object_version.object.sales_set.all()
```

But I get the newest versions of these related objects.
So, how can I get an old versions of Sales?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way:

You should revert current revision of object, get related objects and revert the revision again. Like this:

```
version.revision.revert()
sales = version.object.sales_set.all()
version.revision.revert()
```